# Crash when switching from hard coded string array to getStringArray()

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, android-arrayadapter

I have a simple ArrayAdapter that is filled with a string array.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            numbers_text);
```

Everything works fine when I pass in a string like this.

```
String[] numbers_text = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
```

But when I declare the string this way, it crashes.

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] numbers_text = res.getStringArray(R.array.Planets);
```

Is there any logic error I'm missing here?

xml string array:

```
<string-array name="Planets">
    <item>Sun</item>
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
    <item>Jupiter</item>
    <item>Saturn</item>
    <item>Uranus</item>
    <item>Neptune</item>
</string-array>
```

Edit: Posted updated code with string declarations moved into functions

```
public class SimpleListFragment extends ListFragment
{
Resources res = getActivity().getResources();

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String[] numbers_digits = res.getStringArray(R.array.Planets);
    new CustomToast(getActivity(), numbers_digits[(int) id]);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] numbers_text = res.getStringArray(R.array.Planets);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            numbers_text);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

Comment: but where you called `getResources()` ?

Comment: stack trace would be nice...

Comment: @MD Hi there, I tried your solution before you deleted your answer. Sorry, I don't know who downvoted your answer. Still crashes though.

Comment: what you posted looks good. The only thing I could think of, is that you  have `String[] numbers_text = res.getStringArray(R.array.Planets);`  as  class member

Comment: @Blackbelt Hi there. Yes, it's a member of my fragment class. Is that bad?

Comment: it's. move it in one of the callback, e.g. `onCreateView`

Comment: Is it a fragment or activity?

Comment: @Blackbelt Still crashes, posted whole fragment code, sorry should've posted up code earlier.

Comment: @coolBoy fragment, posted up code class, should've done so earlier

Comment: `ListFragment`, you need a layout which contains a ListView with id `"@android:id/list"` , and you probably want to call the super as first thing

Comment: I had a similar problem long time ago and it turned out that this came because I had more than one strings.xml for different languages. Maybe You forgot to put this String array in every strings.xml...

Comment: @Blackbelt But it works fine when the arrays are declared hard coded outside the functions right above onListItemClick()

Comment: @atsay714 the problem is still `getResources()`. It goes in the method context, like getStringArray. I thought it was clear

Comment: @Blackbelt omg thank you... it works. Sorry, I'm still new at java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to access the Resources you need a valid `Context`. Move the initialization of your `numbers_text`, in on of the callback, eg 
`onCreateView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  String[] numbers_text = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Planets);

  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        numbers_text);
  setListAdapter(adapter);
  return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable `res`, but initiate it in `onCreate(...)`, like:

```
public class SimpleListFragment extends ListFragment
{
    Resources res;

    @Override
    onCreate(...)
    {
        res = getActivity().getResources();

    } 

}
```

then you acn use `res` in class scope